# C# ActionBlock Equivalent that collects results

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm currently using an ActionBlock to process serially started asynchronous jobs. It works very well for processing each item Posted to it, but there is no way to collect a list of the results from each job.

What can I use to collect the results of my jobs in a thread safe manner?

My code is currently something like this:

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int> (async i => await Process(i));
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    actionBlock.Post(i);
}
actionBlock.Complete();
await actionBlock.Completion;
```

I've tried using a TransformBlock instead, but it hangs indefinitely when awaiting the Completion. The completion's status is "WaitingForActivation".

My code with the TransformBlock is something like this:

```
var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, string> (async i => await Process(i));
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    actionBlock.Post(i);
}
actionBlock.Complete();
await actionBlock.Completion;
transformBlock.TryReceiveAll(out IList<string> strings);
```

Comment: Your `TransformBlock` simply couldn't unload it's output buffer so it will hang. An easy solution is to have your `ActionBlock` add items to concurrent collection like a `ConcurrentBag`.

Comment: Thanks, That's pretty much what I've ended up with, but I rambled around a bit first, so I'm using a Parallel.Foreach, which made the code much more succinct.

Comment: To collect all the results of an `TransformBlock` as a `Task<List<T>>`, you could use the method `ToListAsync` that is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714155/tpl-how-do-i-split-and-merge-the-dataflow/58751948#58751948).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out a ConcurrentBag is the answer

```
var bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int> (async i => 
   bag.Add(await Process(i))
);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    actionBlock.Post(i);
}
actionBlock.Complete();
await actionBlock.Completion;
```

Now 'bag' has all the results in it, and can be accessed as an IEnumerable.

The code I've actually ended up using uses a Parallel.ForEach instead of the ActionBlock.

```
Parallel.ForEach
(
    inputData, 
    i => bag.Add(await Process(i))
);
```

This is quite a lot simpler, but seems about as good for performance and still has options to limit the degree of parallelism etc.